# Hash algorithm for small files

Tags: algorithm, hash

There was a hash algorithm that I came across some time ago that was quite useful for small files. From memory the algorithm itself was very simple. It involved adding the hash with the next byte and multiplying by some fixed number (33 maybe?) then there was a bit shift at the end.

The pseudocode looked something like the following:

```
for each byte:
    x = nextbyte * 33
    hash += x
    hash <<= 4
```

Does anyone know the name of this hash algorithm?

Comment: seems to me that the hash will only depend on the last 8 bytes or so due to the shift at the end

Comment: The particular example I gave is not exactly correct but it was along those lines. It's not perfect but it will hopefully give an idea of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [java hash code algorithm:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29)

```
public static int calculateHash(String input) {
    int h = 0;
    int len = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        h = 31 * h + input.charAt(i);
    }
    return h;
}
```

But it in case this is not true try scrolling through the [list of hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions)

Comment: It looks very similar. :) thanks for pointing out where it came from.